# from php to python - dealing without braces

Tags: php, python, formatting

i am a PHP developer by... well that's just what i picked up from a need to develop web services. since than i've found a need to start using python for various projects. one of the first things that has pissed me off is the obsession "properly" indenting code. now i understand its purpose. however, what i have found is that not using `{ }` in my code blocks tends to cause me some periods of wtf.

because of this, i find myself doing stuff like

```py
if a is not None:
  for x in a:
      print x
  # endfor
# endif
```

this seems to help me keep my code in order and visually i can see whats in scope to the loop and control statement.

so what are some other people doing out there that come from the land of `{` and `;` ? or am i the only maniac with this issue?

Comment: If you absolutely must use braces you can use `from __future__ import braces`

Comment: I generally tend to stick to editors that show vertical lines between indentations, so that I can logically see where the end of a block occurs.

Comment: @dckuehn i like the vertical line idea. just need to see if that will work in eclipse. i assume something similar to np++ ?

Comment: Sublime Text is a text editor and PyCharm is a full IDE that both have a vertical line to show indents. Both have paid and free versions.

Comment: Just spent your time with python, then sure you will ask `from python to (php/c like syntax) - dealing with braces and ;`

Comment: that almost looks like ruby, sigh.  you should switch to a text editor that shows indents - many win/max/terminal editors do that. in terms of other issues, at least you're not doing `if (a is not None):`

Comment: `to help me keep my code in order and visually i can see whats in scope` -> this may be an indication to split the code in more functions and write it in a more concise way. If you can't see where each block starts/ends, try to simplify. Alternatively, maybe you're putting too many blocks inside each other. If you're at 5 indents or more, that's a code smell on its own.

Comment: @viraptor - i've had some strange times with `vim` :) although great advice in general. i do in fact stick to what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to adapt to the awesomeness of python. If you're a long time braces users, it will take some time, but eventually you'll love it.

Also, a blank line sometimes goes a long way to improve readability

```
if a is not None:
    for o in objects
        for attribute in o
            do_something_with_the_attribute(attribute)
            do_something_with_the_attribute(attribute)
            ...
            still_using_the_attribute(attribute)

        do_something_with_the_object(o)
        other_things_using_object(o)
        c = 2+2
        if o.something != c:
            print 5

    do_something_with_a(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python deliberately makes this difficult.

Why?  To stop you making too deeply nested a logic pile.

If you stick to 80 characters width, and 4 spaces indentation, then as soon as it begins to be even slightly annoying or confusing, it's python's way of saying, "Dude! Split this monster up into smaller functions before it grows teeth and gnaws you arm off!".

One rule of thumb is that any function, or method, should be able to fit almost completely on screen at once (Including docstring).  If it's longer than that, you should split it up.

Don't be religious about it, but if you stick to this, it really does lead to very clean, clear code bases.

Answer (score 0):

1 )

do **not** do

`from __future__ import braces`

python will troll you with the following if you do

```
>>> from __future__ import braces
SyntaxError: not a chance
```

basically python is telling you no because python is not coded for php and javascript like syntax

its coded to tell you no

to python coders/devs its considered an inside joke but its cruel to tell someone to do that when they are asking for help

2)
(if your using python 2.7.5 or older than your fine)

for python 3.x your code is broken as it will return a syntax error

```
>>> a = "hsfjsdhfjdhfdhfdhf"
>>> if a is not None:
        for x in a:
                print x

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

you forgot ()

it should look like this

```
>>> a = "hsfjsdhfjdhfdhfdhf"
>>> if a is not None:
        for x in a:
                print(x)

h
s
f
j
s
d
h
f
j
d
h
f
d
h
f
d
h
f
```

also `{}` is a dict in python and since python has strict syntax rules you wont be able to wrap code in it only strings in the following formats

```
{"lol":"omg"}
{"lol":"omg","wow":"omg"}
{"lol":{"wow":"omg","pfft":"lolwut"}}
{"lol":["lol","omg","pfft","lolwut"]}
{"lol":[["lol","omg"],["pfft","lolwut"]]}
```

and numerous other ways

also you can infinetly place a dict inside a dict as long as a key exists the value can be a dict, list, tuple, or string

example:

```
{"lol":{"wow":{"omg":{"pfft":"lolwut"}}}}
```

only thing is

it gets harder to split that if you dont know what to do

3)

the one thing i recommend you do is get a nice big book on python and start reading

that's the best way to learn python

especially if you want your projects to be good

or if you want to learn online

start with this

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/

and then move onto this

Datastructures and Algorithms (below is the link)

http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/index.html

or you can do both it doesnt really matter which order you do it in so long as you learn something

Comment: I believe print x is valid in earlier versions of python.

Comment: 2.7.5 is the only one i know that does so ill edit it also i do not recommend using old versions of python in my opinion that is bad practice as it will lead to your code being outdated

Comment: I agree that he should be using the newer version of python, I just wanted to be clear in case he isn't and your fix led to a new problem with his print.

Comment: lots of good stuff in there for sure. however, the version is of no concern here. i am limited to 2.7 as this is the current supported version that my company is using. i can not go around that.